# select count on list using linq on specific value vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am having an issue getting the results I am looking for.  What I need to do is essentially:

```sql
Select count(invoicenbr) from invoicelist where invoicenbr = 'invoice'
```

but when I try it in linq I am not getting the correct results.

When I try to execute the linq query below, it gives me the count for the entire list, and not for the `where invoicenbr = 'invoice'`...

Here is my linq query that is returning the count for the entire invoiceList:

```vb
Dim test = (From invoices In invoicelist _
Where e.Row.Cells("invoicenbr").Value = invoice).count()
```

Comment: Remove the Count() bit.

Comment: That *really* should work as it as now. If you remove the `Count()` and look at the results, what do you see in `e.Row.Cells("invoicenbr").Value`?

Comment: What is `invoicelist` and `e.Row` at all?

Comment: I removed the Count() bit, and the e.row.cells("invoicenbr").Value is 55152, which is an invoice number.  @Tim the invoicelist is a list(of string) that contains invoice numbers.  The e.row is "e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowEventArgs".  I am trying to see the duplicates in my infragistics grid, and then change the background color to alert the user they have duplicate invoice numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a naming issue in your code, i assume that it's responsible for your problem.

The variable in your query is `invoices` but later you use `invoice` to compare it with the cell value, so you have a different variable in scope with name `invoice`.

This should work:

```
Dim invoicenbr As String = e.Row.Cells("invoicenbr").Value
Dim duplicates =  From invoice In invoicelist 
                  Where invoice = invoicenbr 
Dim duplicateCount As Int32 = duplicates.Count()
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, this gives me the count for the specific invoice I am looking for.  I am just having an issue now with the appearance of the cell on the infragistics ultragrid not changing colors, but I will figure it out.  Thanks.